# ¿Es posible generar codigo para que se ejecute en un google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

en el proyecto que estoy desarrollando tengo una hoja de calculo Google que lanza una función que genera un nuevo Google Form.
El problema está en que para enlazarlo con un nuevo spreadsheet que recoja las respuestas, aparte de crear un nuevo spreadsheet, tengo que ejecutar un código que se lanza mediante disparador cada vez que se envia el formulario.

```
function generarFormulari(carpetaTreball,aF,tF,iF,sessions){
  const cT=DriveApp.getFolderById(carpetaTreball);
  const formulari=FormApp.create(aF);
  const idFormulari=formulari.getId();
  const arxiu=DriveApp.getFileById(idFormulari).moveTo(cT);
  formulari.setTitle(tF);
  formulari.setDescription(iF);
  
  const cognoms=formulari.addTextItem();
  cognoms.setTitle("Cognoms:")
  .setRequired(true);

  const nom=formulari.addTextItem();
  nom.setTitle("Nom:")
  .setRequired(true);

}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Al igual que he generado el formulario con los controles que incluye mediante codigo GAS, es posible generar dentro del formulario el código que debe ejecutar el formulario cada vez que se envia?

Igual que he añadido los controles ¿podria agregar la funcion para mover las respuestas a la hoja de calculo, y activar el disparador para que ejecute la funcion cuando se envia el formulario?

Gràcies.

Answer (score 0):

Cada formulario de Google contiene un proyecto de Google Apps Script, esto quiere decir que cada proyecto es independiente y ejecuta código que corresponda únicamente al proyecto (a menos que uses Fetch), sin embargo, en cada proyecto debes especificar los eventos (triggers) que estarán habilitados y la función a ejecutar. Por lo que nos indicas no es posible hacer lo que requieres.

Te recomiendo hacer uso de una WebApp de Google Apps Script con la que puedes implementar formularios propios haciendo uso de HTML, CSS y JS.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Gracias Jailer por tu tiempo y tu ayuda. Ya he gerado el Form con GAS, en el codigo esta la generacion del formulario y la inclusion de dos de las preguntas del formulario. Lo que pretendo y no se si es posible, es gererar deda GAS es la vinculacion a un spreadSheet, los triggers y el codigo que se debe ejecutar con cada respuesta del formulario.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que necesitas es que cuando se envíe el formulario y los datos lleguen a la hoja de respuestas.. dependiendo de esta respuesta realizar algunas acciones. Si es así, entonces puedes irte a la hoja de respuestas (spreadsheet) y en la sección de complementos dar click en Google Apps Script. Eso te abrirá el Editor de GAS para esa hoja, entonces allí podrás crear el Trigger que se ejecutará cuando se reciba una respuesta. Para ampliar la información sigue este enlace https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYQE9ltt2Yg